# jQuery selected radio button index among different sets of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating multiple sets of radio buttons grouped under different names, using jQuery append() function.

Each group has multiple radio buttons and has different group name. Now the problem is that I want to be able to find the index of the selected radio button for a specific group with jQuery. Not sure what to do

```
<input type='radio' name='group1' value='g1v1'>
<input type='radio' name='group1' value='g1v2'>
<input type='radio' name='group2' value='g2v1'>
<input type='radio' name='group2' value='g2v2'>
```

and now selecting the checked radio button for group1 with jQuery with

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='group1']:checked").index();
```

gives me 0 always. I am not sure where I am doing it wrong and what to do.

Comment: And when you are selecting checked radios, what (is) event? Could you provide more code?

Comment: inside a function where I am creating the radio buttons, I have a delegate function defined for "change" event. Inside this delegate function I am trying to get the index of the selected radio button.

Comment: We need that function, because, written as it is (and based on your description), your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/otbjfLxc/

Comment: oh I am not sure how to put that function here, it is connecting to the db through asp.net controller, a jason object is returned and then based on that object radio buttons and their groups are created. While creating the groups I need to add a delegate to the change event of each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not grouping radio buttons using different container then `index()` will not work in this case. You can use **[`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)** method for this. On change of radio button get the `name` of it and select all previous radio button with this `name`and then get the `length` of them like following.

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[type='radio']", function() {
    var index = $(this).prevAll("[name=" + this.name + "]").length;
    alert(index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='group1' value='g1v1'>G1 0
<input type='radio' name='group1' value='g1v2'>G1 1
<input type='radio' name='group1' value='g1v3'>G1 2
<input type='radio' name='group2' value='g2v1'>G2 0
<input type='radio' name='group2' value='g2v2'>G2 1
<input type='radio' name='group2' value='g2v3'>G2 2
```

Comment: Ok in case I am grouping them in different field sets then the simple index() would be enough?

Comment: Yes it would. @Novice